# how get file size in bytes through gulp task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have an APK file in my source folder and I just want to get the size of that file (in bytes) with a gulp task and update that size in an XML file.

Below is my gulp task:

```js
gulp.task('geteditmscript', function(){
    gulp.src("source/deployment.xml")
        .pipe(xeditor([
            {path: '//SCRIPT', attr: {'revision': json.version}},
            {path: '//APP', attr: {'size': gulp.src('source/*.apk').pipe(size())}}
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("source/"));
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `gulp.src('source/*.apk').pipe(size())` doesn't return a file size. It returns a [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).

And while `gulp-size` gives you access to the total size of all files via its [`.size` property](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-size#sizesize) this is only available **after** all files have been processed.

That means you need to delay your `xeditor()` stream until after the `size()` stream has finished. You can do that by placing it into an `on('finish', ...)` handler:

```
gulp.task('geteditmscript', function(cb) {

  var apkSize = size();

  gulp.src('source/*.apk')
    .pipe(apkSize)
    .on('finish', function() {

      gulp.src("source/deployment.xml")
        .pipe(xeditor([
          {path: '//SCRIPT', attr: {'revision': json.version}},
          {path: '//APP', attr: {'size': apkSize.size }}
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("source/"))
        .on('end', cb);

    });
});
```

Comment: the above gulp task also has same issue , updating size as size="[object Object]"

Comment: Not possible. I have tested the code and it works. You made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Could you please check , xml is not modified with above gulp task                 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SCRIPT now="1" revision="1.0.15">
<FTP local="dc_MyProductivity_release.apk"/>
<APP id="1" ran="0" reboot="0" showprompt="1" size="4998537" source="dc_MyProductivity_release.apk"/>
</SCRIPT>

Comment: The gulp task I posted works fine. Tested it with the XML in your comment and the `size` attribute is correctly modified. The mistake is still on your end. You need to check that the path to your  `deployment.xml` is correct.

Comment: Hi Sven thanks for helping me ,...I understand that my "on finish" . "on end" not triggering...do you have any thoughts..

Comment: Not really. If you're using the exact code I posted both `.on('finish',...)` and `.on('end', ...)` should trigger. If you've made modifications to my code I would have to see those to help you.

Comment: there was gulp dependency issue , its resolved now..Thnks alot for your help

Comment: This also works*******************************gulp.task('geteditmscript', function(){
    var apkSize = size();
    gulp.src("source/deployment.xml")
        .pipe(xeditor([
            {path: '//SCRIPT', attr: {'revision': json.version}},
            {path: '//SCRIPT//APP', attr: {'size':  gulp.src('source/*.apk')
                .pipe(size()).size}}
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("source/"));
});**************************